# how to get excel file with react-native-fetch-blob

Tags: javascript, excel, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

I want to fetch an excel file from the server
but i have a warning message

> ### RNFetchBlob error when sending request : null

this is the code :

```
const url ='http://manafeth.ncsi.gov.om/admin/download/countries/import/2018/en?portTypes=land,air,sea&size=100000';
    RNFetchBlob
        .config({
            fileCache : true,
        })
        .fetch('GET', url)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())

        }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log('The error is ', err)
    }
```

)

Comment: is your fetch request correct? I think the structure is more like this: `fetch(url, options)` where options is an object, unless if fetch in react native is different?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network

Comment: @duxfox-- Hello bro,
i'm using the same code to fetch a pdf file and it worked but with the excel is not working

Comment: I don't think that's possible, the fetch function takes 2 arguments in that specific order; url then options. Paste the code for the PDF so we can compare

Comment: @duxfox--
but i use the fetch of RNFetchBlob !!

Comment: oh i see, nvm then

Comment: Is that url valid? Copy-pasting it in the browser is not getting any response

Comment: @Milore yes i'm !! i getting an excel file when i pasting in the browser

Comment: Have you tried passing it a header object after the url? I mean something like `.fetch('GET', url, { 'Content-Type' : 'octet-stream' }).then(...)`

Comment: @Milore the same problem with the header object and without it !!!